# Fuel SDK java: NullPointerException in login

Tags: marketing-cloud, exception, fuel-sdk, java, null-pointer

I am using fuel-java-1.0.1. Using the following code for login:

```
ETConfiguration configuration = new ETConfiguration();
configuration.set("clientId", "my-client-id");
configuration.set("clientSecret", "my-client-secret");
ETClient client = new ETClient(configuration);
```

Intermittently, it fails with the following exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.exacttarget.fuelsdk.ETClient.<init>(ETClient.java:131) ~[fuel-java-1.0.1.jar:?]
```

How to resolve the issue?

**Edit on Oct 13, 2016:**

Fuel-Java version 1.0.1 was released on Jan 29, 2015.

Latest version is 1.0.3 released on Jul 7, 2015.

Will the latest version help?

Comment: Cross posted by myself: https://github.com/salesforce-marketingcloud/FuelSDK-Java/issues/51

Answer (score 1):

Try our latest Fuel SDK Java v1.2.0
https://github.com/salesforce-marketingcloud/FuelSDK-Java

Hope it will solve your issue.
Thanks.